# IDE will not upload to ATTiny88

Tags: arduino-ide, atmega328, attiny

I was successfully compiling sketches and uploading to various MCUs, including the ATTiny88.  Suddenly the IDE quit compiling and complained of various missing compilers.  I found and corrected an issue with my anti-virus, which helped some.  Eventually I uninstalled and wiped the entire IDE.  I then reinstalled from scratch, and now everything compiles OK, butt he IDE will not upload the code to the ATTiny88.  This is done a bit differently than other MCUs.  Instead of creating a virtual com port, the driver creates a different virtual USB device, and then searches for the MCU on that USB device.  The driver should cause the "unknown" MCU to become known to the system, but this does not happen, despite having installed the drivers.  The IDE, in turn, does not create a specific error when uploading, but merely times out.  How can I get the virtual driver working again?  I am running IDE 1.8.13 on a Windows 7 PC.
[image: Device Manager]
[image: Digistump Drivers]
[image]

Comment: Go into Properties on your "Unknown Device", go to Details tab, show the Hardware Ids property values.

Answer (score 0):

There is an updated driver that fixes the issue. It will still show as unknown, however it will properly connect for programming when you reset or power up the ATTiny. NOTE: One component will say it failed during install, but it doesn't matter, ignore it, it will work.

Driver is here: https://github.com/MHEtLive/MHEtLiveArduino/releases/download/1.0.0/2.0a4.rar